# Pytorch delete features columns from dataset

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader, huggingface-datasets

I have a dataset below and would like to ***delete features*** From A - F
the dataset are converted from python dataframe

```
dataset = datasets.DatasetDict({"train":Dataset.from_pandas(X_train),
                        "test":Dataset.from_pandas(X_test),
                        "val":Dataset.from_pandas(X_val),
                      })
```

The dataset output like below

```
DatasetDict({
train: Dataset({
    features: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'text', '__index_level_0__', 'label'],
    num_rows: 1173
})
test: Dataset({
    features: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'text', '__index_level_0__', 'label'],
    num_rows: 1369
})
val: Dataset({
    features: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'text', '__index_level_0__', 'label'],
    num_rows: 1369
})
```

})

Result like below

```
DatasetDict({
train: Dataset({
    features: ['text', '__index_level_0__', 'label'],
    num_rows: 1173
})
test: Dataset({
    features: ['text', '__index_level_0__', 'label'],
    num_rows: 1369
})
val: Dataset({
    features: ['text', '__index_level_0__', 'label'],
    num_rows: 1369
})
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the `remove_columns()` method from datasets. This works on any `Dataset()` object, if you want to remove some columns at this level and not in Pandas before.

```
dataset = dataset.remove_columns("label")
```

For your case, it would be:

```
dataset = dataset.remove_columns(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
```

You can have a look here: https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/process

Comment: thanks Timbus, do you have github, so that i can learn more from you

Comment: I have a github but this is just something of the top of my head, I have used this function before